# How to say "I thought you'd want to know about this"

Tags: futuro

How would you say "I thought you'd want to know about this." ... The best I could come up with was "Pensé que querrás saber sobre esto."

Is this correct?

Comment: I'll let others come up with a more idiomatic way, but tense wise, you'd probably want *pensaba* and *querrías*, though *pensé* is certainly possibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't correct. I find better to say:

1. Pensé que querrías saber de esto.
2. Pensé que querrías saber sobre esto.
3. Pensé que querrías saber acerca de esto.

The deference between *de esto, sobre esto* and *acerca de esto* is rather a matter of taste, mean the same, but some may seem more common than another. In my experience, the option 1 is the most common, and the 3 the most unusual and in some way a little formal.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the speaker is about to tell the listener that thing he thinks he wants to know. In this case, the correct verb tense is the past perfect.

Additionally, if he is about to say a specific thing and not a series of things related to a single topic, we would omit the equivalent of *about*. All together:

> He pensado que te gustaría saber esto. / He pensado que querrías saber
> esto.

If the speaker has just said the thing, this would be better:

> He pensado que te gustaría saberlo. / He pensado que querrías saberlo.

The verb *querer* is more appropriate if the news is unpleasant for the listener. Putting in context:

> Paco ha conseguido el trabajo que gustaba. He pensado que te gustaría
> saberlo.
>
> He pensado que querrías saber esto: Pepe tuvo un accidente y está en
> el hospital.